# Embed select in the select missing operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have an [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) database and I tried to concat some values in a field as follows:

```
SELECT ('29434-'&`book`.id&'-'&`book`.page&'-'&`book`.part&(select count(`title`.tit) from `title` where `title`.id = `book`.id) AS ID,
`book`.nass AS content, `book`.part, `book`.page FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.id, `book`.page
```

I have got an error message about a missing operator. The concat works fine without the embed select. How could I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to close the first parenthesis. I'm not too sure where you have to close it though, or you might delete the first one as this

```
SELECT '29434-'&`book`.id&'-'&`book`.page&'-'&`book`.part&(select count(`title`.tit) from `title` where `title`.id = `book`.id) AS ID,
`book`.nass AS content, `book`.part, `book`.page FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.id, `book`.page
```